# MySQL - line-based update to a text field

Tags: mysql

I have a text field that holds SQL for reports that users can run, and I need to replace '#' and '--' comments with the '/* */' format.

e.g.

```
select -- foobar
idnam #barfoo
-- hello world
from p_person;
```

should become:

```
select /* foobar*/
idnam /*barfoo*/
/* hello world*/
from p_person;
```

Any suggestions as to how to approach this? Replacing the opening /* is not a problem - it's the closing one that's foxing me. The MySQL version is 5.7.23.

Comment: Without regex_replace, you will struggle to do this as you do not know the number of lines and comments to replace. I would get the queries out of mysql, replace the comments in an external programming language and save the results back to the database.

Comment: Does 4-lines text is a value of your 'text field' in one row?

Comment: With MySQL 5.7, you'll be better off fetching the text to a client application, editing the text with string functions provided by your programming language, and then updating the altered text to the database. If there is a way to do this task in MySQL 5.7, the SQL code will be complex and difficult to maintain.

Comment: Or you could upgrade to MySQL 8.0 (which supports a [`REGEXP_REPLACE()`  function](https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/new-regular-expression-functions-in-mysql-8-0/)) which you should be doing by October 2023 anyway, because that's when 5.7 terminates support.